# If $Q \in\mathrm{Spec}(B)$ is the unique prime ideal lying over $P \in\mathrm{Spec}(A)$, then $B_P=B_Q$.

Tags: commutative-algebra, localization, integral-extensions

> Let $A \subseteq B$ be an integral extension of integral domains. Suppose $P \in \mathrm{Spec}(A)$ and $Q \in \mathrm{Spec}(B)$ is the unique prime ideal lying above $P$. Prove that $B_Q=B_P$.

My attempt: since $P=Q\cap A \subseteq Q$, we have $B_Q \subseteq B_P$. For the converse, suppose $b/s \in B_P$. Then $s \not\in P$. Since $P=Q \cap A$, we have $s \not\in Q \cap A$. That is, $s \not\in Q$ or $s \not\in A$. If it's the former, then that's what we want. If it's the latter, how should I arrive at a contradiction?

I don't know how to use the condition that $B$ is integral over $A$. If $s$ satisfies the equation $s^n+a_{n-1}s^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1s+a_0=0$ for some $a_{n-1},\ldots,a_0 \in A$. What can that do for me?

Can anyone give me a hint? Thank you!

Comment: Actually it is obvious that $B_P\subseteq B_Q$. The other containement has to be proved.

Answer (score 2):

Look at $B_P|_{A_P}$ which is an integral extension. The fact that only one prime lies over $PA_P$ implies $B_P$ is local. Also observe that $QB_P$ has to be the unique maximal ideal of $B_P$. Thus anything outside $Q$ is a unit in $B_P$ and hence $B_Q$ =$B_P$

Comment: Why does $B_P$ is local implies $B_Q=B_P$? I couldn't follow this step.

Comment: @bbw $B_P\subset B_Q$ since you are inverting more elements. Now take any element $s$ with $s \in B-Q$. So $s$ is outside $QB_P$ and hence a unit in $B_P$ Thus all elements of $B-Q$ are already inverted.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly $B_P\subseteq B_Q$. In order to prove that $B_P=B_Q$ notice that $B_Q$ is the localization of $B_P$ at $QB_P$. Now let's prove that $B_P$ is a local ring and its maximal ideal is $QB_P$. Any prime ideal of $B_P$ is of the form $Q'B_P$ with $Q'\cap A\subseteq P$. Since $Q$ is the only prime ideal lying over $P$ we have $Q'\cap A\subsetneq P$ provided $Q'\ne Q$. By Going Up there is a prime ideal $Q''$ of $B$ (strictly) containing $Q'$ and lying over $P$. By hypothesis $Q''=Q$, and thus $Q'\subsetneq Q$ proving that $QB_P$ is the only maximal ideal.

Comment: Why is $B_Q$ the localization of $B_P$ at $QB_P$? $B_Q$ is $(B \setminus Q)^{-1} B$ and the other is $(B_P \setminus QB_P)^{-1}B_P$. And I still don't understand why $B_P$ is local $\Rightarrow$ $B_P=B_Q$. Can you explain a little bit more?

Comment: If $S=A\setminus P$, then $Q\cap S=\emptyset$ and a well known property of localization says that $(S^{-1}B)_{S^{-1}Q}$ is isomorphic to $B_Q$. But $S^{-1}B=B_P$, and $S^{-1}Q=QB_P$.

Comment: If $R$ is a local ring with maximal ideal $\mathfrak m$ then $R_{\mathfrak m}=R$ since every element in $R\setminus\mathfrak m$ is invertible in $R$.

Comment: Thank you for you explanation!